# An expression for someone who makes difficulties for himself

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a word or expression for someone who is often a cause of difficulties that he later has to overcome?

For example, a man who always has to work extra hours to finish his job at time just because when he *has* time he slacks instead working.

Or maybe a good chess player that makes silly mistakes because he always underestimates his opponent (and later has to try hard to compensate for these mistakes).

So basically I want a word or expression for someone who makes avoidable and totally unnecessary difficulties for himself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bit of a neologism, but I suppose "self-saboteur" captures the person you are describing adequately.

If you don't necessarily need a single word you could go with the more traditional:

> He has a habit of shooting himself in the foot

Answer (score 7):

You could say

> He is his own worst enemy.

or

> He can't get out of his own way.

Answer (score 2):

If I were an employer describing this person to a third party, I would call him/her:

> A Liability

If I were describing this person generally, I would use:

> Self-destructive

More generally:

> A trainwreck

Or, even moreso, and in the strictest sense of the word:

> A fool

Comment: Pretty sure that *him/her* is not a word.

Answer (score 2):

If an adjective will suffice, "improvident" or "shortsighted" or any of their [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/shortsighted?s=t) should work.

Your question's phrasing suggests that maybe you want a noun.  A "[micawber](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/micawber?s=t)" is a person who assumes that things will be better in the future and thus avoids working hard in the present moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that he

> shoots himself in the foot.